# Restarting youtube-dl

Tags: ubuntu, youtube-dl

I feel like this should be a really simple thing to do, but I don't know how to do it.

I recently updated the config file for [youtube-dl](https://github.com/rg3/youtube-dl) and I also upgraded to the latest version. The update message says to restart the program to complete the upgrade, but I cannot for the life of me figure out how. The documentation doesn't give a command to do so, and running `service youtube-dl restart` returns that the service cannot be found.

I installed it using the manual installation method and thus upgraded using `youtube-dl -U`. I'm on Ubuntu Server 14.10.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

There is no permanently running service.  The message given after update is kind of confusing, but basically means that if you have an instance of youtube-dl running  currently, it must be restarted to benefit from the update.  Since it rarely takes longer to download a video, than it does to update, I suspect the number of people who actually 'need' to restart anything is close to zero.

Comment: Ah, perfect. I had to log out and log in again from a different location, and upon logging back in I checked the version and it was indeed the new version. (I assume you're correct in that it updated immediately, I'm just reporting the full story that I had to log out/in). The main reason I asked was because I updated the config file but it was still using the old config for new downloads, but that has resolved itself now as well. Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

You don't have to do anything, this means that if its running right now then you have to stop it and start again, such as:

```
pkill youtube-dl
```